# Spring: declare variable XML in java class and populateDatabase

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I want to introduce a String variable in my domain model. The contents of the variable will be an xml text, and that's where the question arises.

I want to enter the string variable in my Bpmsn class:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Bpmsn extends DomainEntity {

// Attributes ---------------------------------------------------------
private String ticker;
private String title;
private String summary;
private Date authoredMoment;
private boolean public_;
private int likes;      //Derived
private int dislikes;   //Derived


@NotBlank
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "^(\\d{6})\\-([a-zA-Z]{4})$")
@Column(unique=true)
@SafeHtml
public String getTicker() {
    return ticker;
}

public void setTicker(String ticker) {
    this.ticker = ticker;
}

@NotBlank
@NotNull
@SafeHtml
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@NotBlank
@NotNull
@SafeHtml
public String getSummary() {
    return summary;
}

public void setSummary(String summary) {
    this.summary = summary;
}

@NotNull
@Past
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
public Date getAuthoredMoment() {
    return authoredMoment;
}

public void setAuthoredMoment(Date authoredMoment) {
    this.authoredMoment = authoredMoment;
}

public boolean getIsPublic_() {
    return public_;
}

public void setIsPublic_(boolean public_) {
    this.public_ = public_;
}

@Min(0)
public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}
public void setLikes(int likes){
    this.likes = likes;
}

@Min(0)
public int getDislikes() {
    return dislikes;
}
public void setDislikes(int dislikes){
    this.dislikes = dislikes;
}
```

The first question is if I need any annotation of type @XML ....

```
private String textXML;

public String getTextXML() {
  return textXML;
}

public void setTextXML(String textXML) {
  this.textXML = textXML;
}
```

Once finished with this I need to enter some data in the database to do tests. 
To do this I use the file PopulateDatabase.xml provided by Spring. My other question is how to declare a String attribute with xml text in the PopulateDatabase.xml file that looks like:

```
<bean id="bpmsn1" class="domain.Bpmsn">
    <property name="ticker" value="161018-aaaa" />
    <property name="title" value="Test" />
    <property name="summary" value="Testeando un poco" />
    <property name="authoredMoment" value="10/18/2016 13:45" />
    <property name="likes" value="2" />
    <property name="dislikes" value="0" />
    <property name="user" ref="user1" />
    <property name="isPublic_" value="true" />
    <property name="opinions">
        <list>
            <ref bean="opinion1" />
            <ref bean="opinion2" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="comments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="comment2" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

That's how it goes wrong

```
<property name="textXML" value="
  <?xml%20version='1.0'%20encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
 ">
```